# TortoiseSVN how do you Disable/Enable TSVNCache.exe via Command Line?

Tags: tortoisesvn, tsvncache

I'm trying to disable (and enable) TSVNCache in a BAT Script, is it possible? or do I need to kill it? Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes optimizing it is what you are looking for: http://www.nivas.hr/blog/2011/09/27/speed-up-tortoisesvn-cache-process-tsvncache-exe-and-lower-your-disk-io-activity/

Answer (score 40):

In a Windows Explorer Window, right-click on any file, then
go to **TortioseSVN->Settings->Icon Overlays->Status Cache** and set it to **None**.

tsvncache.exe will immediately exit and not run again.

Comment: That was correct in the past, but it no longer seems to work (I just did this and I still have 2 TSVNCache.exe)

Comment: @Timores That might be other user sessions running on the computer.

Answer (score 15):

It seems your problem is to reduce Disk I/O. If you really need to use command line for reduce priority, I recommend you use PrcView: http://www.teamcti.com/pview/prcview.htm

If command line use is not mandatory, try to disable cache. In TortoiseSVN Settings, under Icon Overlays, set your Status cache to either Shell or None.

Comment: `It seems your problem is to reduce Disk I/O.` Where did you get that? They didn’t say anything about it being about disk I/O. In my case, I want to turn it off because I don’t use TSVN frequently enough to justify having an extraneous process running all the time; nothing at all to do with disk I/O.

Comment: In my case, I had enormous swapping (thus, disk I/O) with TSVNCache working.

Comment: And you're not the only one, googling `disable tsvncache` brings up a few pages with excessive disk I/O as well, but that is not the only reason to want to disable it, and the OP said nothing about it. That’s why I questioned your unfounded conclusion. That said, your suggestion of `Icon Overlays → Status Cache → None` should work to disable it no matter what the issue is. `:-)` (I have yet to see the process start in the past few hours, so hopefully I won’t have to kill it every now and then.)

Answer (score 2):

Write a batch script with this line.  You will need to run the batch script with elevated (administrator) permissions

```
taskkill /f /t /im tsvncache.exe
```

To start it from the command line, another batch file

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Bin\TSVNCache.exe"
```

I'd keep the quotes, around the command because of the space between "Program" and "Files".