# Cannot rename folders containing svn repositories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For some reason, I am unable to rename folders containing local `svn` repositories I have created. When I do this through Total Commander I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot write D:\newname
Please remove the write protection
```

I have checked the process explorer and it seems that TSVNCache.exe is the culprit. The `svn` forums are quite inactive so this is my best shot at getting a solution.

Comment: What happens if you just kill TSVNCache from Task Manager?

Comment: It restarts automatically. It won't give me enough time to go out there and rename the folder.

Comment: There's no such thing as *local* repository. Subversion is a centralised version control system so it only has one kind of repository: *the* repository. Perhaps you're referring to a working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223340/tortoisesvn-how-do-you-disable-enable-tsvncache-exe-via-command-line). One must kill the cache using TortoiseSVN (which is the client I am using).

> In a Windows Explorer Window, right-click on any file, then go to
>   TortioseSVN->Settings->Icon Overlays->Status Cache and set it to None.
>
> tsvncache.exe will immediately exit and not run again.

Very pretentious of Tortoise to think that they are entitled to lock down folder renaming on behalf of the user.

Comment: We don't rename folders very often, and folder lock is just side effect of how Windows function `FindFirstChangeNotification` works. It's not like TortoiseSVN team decided "let's lock these folder and annoy all users".

Comment: Probably not, but precisely the kind of thinking that encourages users to go for git...

Comment: Don't confuse versioning control system (svn vs git) with Windows shell implementation of the one. There is a TortoiseGit shell extension for git, and it also [locks the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16773257) if status cache is set to default.

Comment: I see.... well then perhaps the default in this case should be to not lock the folder

Comment: There must be something else going on in your PC. I copy, move and rename working copies all the time and I rarely have issues. Perhaps you have an IDE, a web server or an antivirus that keeps file open :-?